# SQL query to filter unique status records

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need a SQL Server and Oracle compatible query to get the following result

Table:

```
PRIMARY IDN   SECONDARY_IDN    STATUS 
1             47               Pending
2             47               Completed
3             47               Error
4             57               Pending
5             59               Completed
6             60               Pending
7             60               Completed
```

My input would be either `Pending`, `Completed`, or `Error`.

I need to list out all the secondary IDN with just 1 status and that is the input status.

For example my input is `Pending`: it should show up 57 ONLY. Others might have `Pending` but it also has completed and error records .

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  SECONDARY_IDN
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY SECONDARY_IDN
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/537da/2)

Comment: SQLFIddle is very Interesting

Comment: by the way, what rdbms you are using?

Comment: MSSQL and Oracle at Work , MYSQL at home ( but rarely ) since I am a web developer :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need groups that have only one status.  For that, you want to use aggregation:

```
select secondary_idn
from t
group by secondary_idn
having max(status) = min(status)  and -- all the statuses are the same
       max(status) = 'Pending'        -- and the status is Pending
```

Comment: What is the meaning of max(status) , its a string isnt it ?

Comment: @Nishant . . . Yes, it is a string.  `min()` and `max()` work on strings, characters, and date/time data times.

Comment: This is one of those neat solutions which require a comment in the code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM  tableName tn
WHERE tn.Status = 'Pending'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
  FROM tableName nx
  WHERE nx.SECONDARY_IDN = tn.SECONDARY_IDN
  AND nx.Status <> 'Pending'
  );
```

---

- The outer query has no `group by`, so all columns are available to it (the dreaded `select *` is there to illustrate this fact)
- The `exists` needs to detect *only one* unwanted record to yield `true`, solutions with aggregates (min, max, count) may have to scan (and aggregate) *the whole group* to establish the desirability of the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select status
 , secondary_idn
 , count(*) records
 from theTable
 where whatever
 group by status, secondary_idn
 having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: This one picks up all the cases where there is 'Pending'